# Python - output of function doesn't take in all requirements

Tags: python

We are quite new to the programming world, so excuse us if we're blind for an easy improvement.

We are making a system which has to order grades given to students. 
We have already made a function that can round grades up - it's a request.

Now we have to make a function which can find the mean value of a given sets of grades. But there are some requirements:

- If there is only one grade given - this must be the final grade (this works)
- If there are more than one grade it must delete the lowest grade (this should also work because we have sorted the numbers.
- THE PROBLEM: If there is a grade minus three (-3) given to a student - this grade must be the final grade of one vector of grades.

This is our code:

```
def computeFinalGrades(grades):
   meanGrades = []
   N = np.size(grades[:,0]) 
   M = np.size(grades[0,:])

   for i in range(N):       

     if M == 1:
        grades = grades

     elif M >= 2:
        grades = np.sort(grades)  

        if -3 in grades[:,1}:
           meanGrades.append(-3)

        else:
           grades = np.delete(grades,[0],axis=1)        
           meanGrades.append(np.mean(grades))

     gradesFinal = roundGrade(meanGrades)

  return gradesFinal
```

Thank yoooooou! And have a nice day! :-)

Comment: For better clarity, what does the `roundGrade` method do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

1. This line looks broken:

   ```
   if -3 in grades[:,1}:
   ```

   Maybe you where going to do this:

   ```
   if -3 in grades[:,1]:
   ```
2. This line looks totally useless:

   ```
   grades = grades
   ```